# Must declare the scalar variable "@lblCmpUserName"

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

When a user logs in with his `UserName`, I send the `UserName` to the next page as below code in `Page_Load`

```
 lblCmpUserName.Text = Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["Parameter"].ToString());
```

and then I want to store the "Company details" with the UserName in a SQL Server 2008 table.

I got the error

> Must declare the scalar variable "@lblCmpUserName"

Code:

```
    protected void BtnCmpApproval_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       SqlConnection SqlCon = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
       string query = "INSERT INTO Company_Info2 VALUES (@lblCmpUserName, @txtCmpName,  @txtRegCountry, @txtCmpRegNo, @txtCmpEstdate,@AFU1, @txtCmpAddress, @ddlAddrIn)";
       try
       {
          SqlCon.Open();

          SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, SqlCon);
          cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", lblCmpUserName.Text);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cmp_Name", txtCmpName.Text);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Commercial_RegNo", txtRegCountry.Text);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comm_Country", txtCmpRegNo.Text);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cmp_EstablishDate", txtCmpEstdate.Text);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cmp_DocPath", AFU1.FileName);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtCmpAddress", txtCmpAddress.Text);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ddlAddrIn", ddlAddrIn.SelectedItem.Text);

          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
         throw new Exception(ex.Message);
      }
      finally
      { 
         SqlCon.Close();
      }
    }
```

Comment: instead of storing query string in lblCmpUserName.Text, try to store in another plain variable such i-e string username. And then inside you sqlcommand parameter call 'username'. And then note if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, I made a mistake in my `INSERT` query.

It should be like this.

```
string query="INSERT INTO Company_Info2 VALUES     (@UserName,@Cmp_Name,@Comm_Country,
    @Commercial_RegNo,@Cmp_DocPath,  
    @Cmp_EstablishDate,@Cmp_Address,@IsAddress)";
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
protected void BtnCmpApproval_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    SqlConnection SqlCon = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
    string query = "INSERT INTO Company_Info2 VALUES (@lblCmpUserName,@txtCmpName,
    @txtRegCountry,@txtCmpRegNo,@txtCmpEstdate,@txtCmpAddress,@ddlAddrIn)";
    try
    {
     SqlCon.Open();
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, SqlCon);
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lblCmpUserName", lblCmpUserName.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtCmpName", txtCmpName.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtRegCountry", txtRegCountry.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtCmpRegNo", txtCmpRegNo.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtCmpEstdate", txtCmpEstdate.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cmp_DocPath", AFU1.FileName);

     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtCmpAddress", txtCmpAddress.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ddlAddrIn", ddlAddrIn.SelectedItem.Text);
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
     throw new Exception(ex.Message);
  }
  finally
  { 
           SqlCon.Close();
  }
  }
```

Actually except last two, none of your added parameters match the parameters present in Query.
Parameters defined in Query & Parameter added to the command using

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(...)
```

or

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(...)
```

must be same or else you will get errors for sure.

Answer (score 2):

When you write a SqlCommand as in the code above, it is like you are saying to NET Runtime. "Hey, I'm sending this string `query` to SqlServer with placeholders for the parameters present in the command collection. Please substitute the placeholders with the parameters values you will find in the collection". Now NET Runtime search your string for placeholders, but there is no parameter corrisponding to the placeholder @lblCmpUserName, so it complains with you. (NET stops at the first one, but you have many more after the first one)

```
@lblCmpUserName,   -> No match found 
@txtCmpName,       -> No match found
@txtRegCountry,    -> No match found
@txtCmpRegNo,      -> No match found
@txtCmpEstdate,    -> No match found
@txtCmpAddress,    -> Found match 
@ddlAddrIn         -> Found match
```

Now you have two options, change the placeholders to match the parameters names or change the parameters name to match the placeholders. It's your choice.

Also, when parsing the string `query` the NET runtime will notice that you have 7 placeholders and 8 parameters. THis will be another error. You add the parameter `@Cmp_DocPath` but the string has no placeholder for it-

Answer (score 1):

```
@lblCmpUserName
```

there is no matching

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", lblCmpUserName.Text);
```

line for `@lblCmpUserName.`

add this line:

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lblCmpUserName",  lblCmpUserName.Text);
```

you are still going to get errors tho. For every `@Parameter` you add in your sql statement, you need to have a matching `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue` line.

Comment: I'm having column name "UserName" VARCHAR(16) in my SQL table Company_Info2 for the parameter "@lblUserName".In my web page,the "UserName" of the LoginID is displayed in my Lable control "lblCmpUserName".So i tried to store that (Label control)data with other textboxs and dropdownlist data to my table.Why i'm getting this error ?

Comment: what error? if you use the answers that are provided here there cant be any errors left.. unless there's something else that's wrong in your code but we cant possibly know that